# share a text between two mobile devices using Flutter NFC

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, nfc, lib-nfc

I'm trying to configure NFC in flutter and find a Near by Device using it and while tapping the two devices the text Message should be shared from one device to Another

couldn't able to find any Perfect Example or a Tutorial regarding my requirement any docs or sample code will be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

**To share a text between two mobile devices use Flutter NFC, you can use the flutter_nfc_kit package, which provides a simple and easy-to-use API for working with NFC in Flutter.**

```
**ExampleCode:
```

> ```
> Add the flutter_nfc_kit package to your dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file.**
> ```

**Initialize the NFC module in your main function:

> NFC.instance.start();

> NFC.instance.share("Your message here");

- 

---

---

> **NFC.instance.onShareSuccess.listen((event) {   print(event.shareData); });

NFC.instance.isAvailable**

Comment: Yeah I tried …But I need some sample code or a Blog to get a better understanding!

Comment: did you tried something like that?

Comment: No I Need to try it Let me Try it and Let you Know....Thanks for the example.